# Triggering Azure Function when resources are created

Tags: azure

Is it possible (in python) to trigger an Azure functions for when a defined type of a resource is being created (e.g. a private endpoint)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Azure Event Grid trigger for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid-trigger?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203).

Basically you create an Azure EventGrid Topic e. g. on a *Resource Group* or *Subscription* and subscribe with your Azure Function (Event Handler) to events on that topic. Use *filter* to only call your function if a desired resource is created.

It is really easy to set up.

Further reading:

- [What is Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203)
- [Filter events for Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/how-to-filter-events?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203)
- [System topics in Azure Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/system-topics?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203)